# Finding a root that makes this huge polynomial negative

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, theorem-proving

I have the following polynomial.

```
P[y_] = Abs[(1 - (0.` + 0.07746031519319982` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
         0.09713096490596462` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
         0.11290521136530342` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
         0.1543104523227209` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
         0.1643663550989435` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
         0.16548737406015293` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
         0.1881552825358055` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
         0.19197400546206703` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
         0.22342052082962607` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
         0.26298357988150745` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
         0.4139062323983639` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
         0.45635519944296904` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
         1.1299490429781665` I) y)]^2 - 
  3.937120617288008`*^-14 Abs[(0.` - 
       3.599575709269318`*^10 y^750 + (0.` + 
          4.1369578222829004`*^11 I) y^751 + 
       2.0598989195696348`*^12 y^752 - (0.` + 
          5.812817063223797`*^12 I) y^753 - 
       1.020659679238148`*^13 y^754 + (0.` + 
          1.151615734564845`*^13 I) y^755 + 
       8.302837789701031`*^12 y^756 - (0.` + 
          3.6376383713469365`*^12 I) y^757 - 
       8.169501684177294`*^11 y^758 + (0.` + 
          1.4155844385164032`*^10 I) y^759 - 
       3.157306920812451`*^10 y^760 + (0.` + 
          3.236108245829668`*^9 I) y^761 - 
       8.054207066661339`*^8 y^762 + (0.` + 
          7.948663505649126`*^7 I) y^763 - 
       2.7306473070848003`*^7 y^764 + (0.` + 
          3.770534300184887`*^6 I) y^765 - 
       17878.37393655826` y^766 + (0.` + 
          8799.475929888991` I) y^767 - 
       519.5109976114682` y^768)/(y^435 ((0.` + 
            5.898860617750132` I) y^63 + 
         10.44629168600992` y^64)^5)]^2
```

I want to know if it always evaluates to postive value for any possible root $y$ (Real). So I tried Solve[]

```
Solve[Abs[P[y]] < 0, y]
```

But it executes forever. Is there any way to confirm that this polynomial is always postive?

Comment: I'm probably being pedantic, but you do mean "...for any possible *input* $y$ (Real)." right? A "root" would be a specific input value where the polynomial evaluates out to exactly zero by definition - and so your function wouldn't "evaluate to positive value" since it evaluates to precisely zero.

Comment: Yes sorry I have no idea why I said root

Answer (score 3):

Redefining your function

```
Clear[p, y]

p[y_] := 
 Abs[(1 - (0.` + 0.07746031519319982` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
          0.09713096490596462` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
          0.11290521136530342` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
          0.1543104523227209` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
          0.1643663550989435` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
          0.16548737406015293` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
          0.1881552825358055` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
          0.19197400546206703` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
          0.22342052082962607` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
          0.26298357988150745` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
          0.4139062323983639` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
          0.45635519944296904` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
          1.1299490429781665` I) y)]^2 - 
  3.937120617288008`*^-14 Abs[(0.` - 
        3.599575709269318`*^10 y^750 + (0.` + 
           4.1369578222829004`*^11 I) y^751 + 
        2.0598989195696348`*^12 y^752 - (0.` + 
           5.812817063223797`*^12 I) y^753 - 
        1.020659679238148`*^13 y^754 + (0.` + 
           1.151615734564845`*^13 I) y^755 + 
        8.302837789701031`*^12 y^756 - (0.` + 
           3.6376383713469365`*^12 I) y^757 - 
        8.169501684177294`*^11 y^758 + (0.` + 
           1.4155844385164032`*^10 I) y^759 - 
        3.157306920812451`*^10 y^760 + (0.` + 
           3.236108245829668`*^9 I) y^761 - 
        8.054207066661339`*^8 y^762 + (0.` + 
           7.948663505649126`*^7 I) y^763 - 
        2.7306473070848003`*^7 y^764 + (0.` + 
           3.770534300184887`*^6 I) y^765 - 
        17878.37393655826` y^766 + (0.` + 
           8799.475929888991` I) y^767 - 
        519.5109976114682` y^768)/(y^435 ((0.` + 
              5.898860617750132` I) y^63 + 
           10.44629168600992` y^64)^5)]^2
```

Then check with `Reduce`

```
Reduce[ForAll[y, Element[y, Reals], p[y] > 0]]  (* False *)
```

Let's inspect what is going on

```
p[0.1] (* Indeterminate *)
Plot[p[y], {y, -1, 1}]
```

> [image: plot]

Comment: What is the minimum number that is considered 0 and above which we get positive?

Comment: I don’t quite understand. Do you mind rephrasing ?

Comment: Yeah sure sorry I will try. The second answer to this post showed a number  p(y) = -5.92568*10^-14  at y = 10^-2. If it happend that it was -5.92568*10^-19, would  Reduce[ForAll[y, Element[y, Reals], p[y] >= 0]] give true or false?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `FindRoot[p[y], {y, 0.4}]; (*{y -> 0.399272}*)
p[y] /. %; (*4.94803*10^-10*)` ?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously you can not calculate differences with such high exponents using machine precision. Therefore you must rationalize your coefficients . However, your coefficients have only a limited precision and the following could be wrong due to this. Anyway, having no other information I assume that your coefficients are exact.

To rationalize your function write:

```
P[y_] = Rationalize[
  Abs[(1 - (0.` + 0.07746031519319982` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
           0.09713096490596462` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
           0.11290521136530342` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
           0.1543104523227209` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
           0.1643663550989435` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
           0.16548737406015293` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
           0.1881552825358055` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
           0.19197400546206703` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
           0.22342052082962607` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
           0.26298357988150745` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
           0.4139062323983639` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
           0.45635519944296904` I) y) (1 - (0.` + 
           1.1299490429781665` I) y)]^2 - 
   3.937120617288008`*^-14 Abs[(0.` - 
         3.599575709269318`*^10 y^750 + (0.` + 
            4.1369578222829004`*^11 I) y^751 + 
         2.0598989195696348`*^12 y^752 - (0.` + 
            5.812817063223797`*^12 I) y^753 - 
         1.020659679238148`*^13 y^754 + (0.` + 
            1.151615734564845`*^13 I) y^755 + 
         8.302837789701031`*^12 y^756 - (0.` + 
            3.6376383713469365`*^12 I) y^757 - 
         8.169501684177294`*^11 y^758 + (0.` + 
            1.4155844385164032`*^10 I) y^759 - 
         3.157306920812451`*^10 y^760 + (0.` + 
            3.236108245829668`*^9 I) y^761 - 
         8.054207066661339`*^8 y^762 + (0.` + 
            7.948663505649126`*^7 I) y^763 - 
         2.7306473070848003`*^7 y^764 + (0.` + 
            3.770534300184887`*^6 I) y^765 - 
         17878.37393655826` y^766 + (0.` + 
            8799.475929888991` I) y^767 - 
         519.5109976114682` y^768)/(y^435 ((0.` + 
               5.898860617750132` I) y^63 + 
            10.44629168600992` y^64)^5)]^2, 10^-20]
```

For y==0 this results in a divide by zero. However for y near zero this gives negative values. E.g.

```
P[10^-2] // N
(* -5.92568*10^-14 *)
```